# Es correcto este codigo de controller?

Tags: eloquent, relaciones

es correcto este código de controlador?

```
$product = Product::find($id)->with('dsa');
```

usando solo este

```
$product = Product::find($id);
```

me funciona correctamente pero al intentar añadir la tabla relacionada no lo consigo lo e intentado de mil formas y nada..
tengo relacionadas las tablas tanto mi base de datos innoDB
coomo en los modelos..

MODELO

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
  protected $fillable = [
     'id', 'nombre', 'apellidos', 'nombreyape', 'nacimiento', 'fallecimiento', 'user_id'
   ]; 
   public function dsa()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Dsa', 'di', 'id');
    }
}
```

Modelo Dsa
    namespace App;

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Dsa extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id', 'di', 'nombre', 'apellidos', 'enlace'
    ];

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Product', 'id', 'di');
    }
```

}

---

usando este controlador

```
$product = Product::with('dsa')->find($id);
```

me funciona para mostrar la tabla completa usando

```
{{ $product->dsa }}
```

y me devuelve esto exactamente

[{"id":10,"user_id":21,"di":39,"nombre":"pepe","apellidos":"lorenzo","enlace":"ejemplo","created_at":"2018-10-06 14:50:37","updated_at":"2018-10-06 14:50:37"},{"id":11,"user_id":21,"di":39,nombre":"juan","apellidos":"mellado","enlace":"ejemplo","created_at":"2018-10-06 14:51:11","updated_at":"2018-10-06 14:51:11"}]

pero si intento llamar algo solo como el nombre por ejemplo

```
{{ $product->dsa->nombre }}
```

me da el siguiente error Property [nombre] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: Pon el modelo Dsa

Comment: a que te refieres con correcto? cual de los dos modos estas usando? cual es la duda clara?

Comment: el que quiro usar es este [code]$product = Product::find($id)->with('dsa'); [/code]  lo que quiero conseguir es mostrar los datos de la tabla Product y la tabla Dsa, gracias por la ayuda

Comment: vas a ocupar el id en tu consulta? o por que lo colocaste con el método find?

Comment: a lo que voy es necesitas filtrar tu busqueda por id?

Comment: necesito filtrar por id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionado era tema de @foreach gracias por la ayuda

Comment: por favor agrega tu respuesta en esta ultima publicación que haces para que a otros usuarios les sirva y te la podamos calificar